# Profiling slow stream_socket_client tcp connection

Tags: php

I need a way of profiling stream_socket_client. It's used for TCP connection, and in docker it takes to fail ~2 sec, while in local setup it fails immediately.

Simple example:

```
$errno = 0;
$errstr = '';
$context = stream_context_create();

$stream = stream_socket_client('tcp://hostname:1234', $errno, $errstr, 0, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

var_dump($errno, $errstr, $context);
```

As a TCP connection has multiple steps, i want to know how much each of them takes for each of them to be finished.

Is there a function, php profiler, or any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately a PHP profiler will not do anything since it doesn't profile into the `stream_socket_client` lower-level code. You'll need to cachegrind a debug version of the php binary instead if you think PHP is the culprit. I don't think it is. Do you get the same poor latency behavior when doing it via good old netcat? What about ping, tracepath? This seems to be a network issue so you'll need network profiling, using pcap and something like wireshark to check every packet timing. So this issue can be approached in multiple ways, but definitely not using a PHP profiler.